# Find the minimum value of $y = \sqrt {{x^2} + 4x + 13} + \sqrt {{x^2} - 8x + 41} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the minimum value of $y = \sqrt {{x^2} + 4x + 13}  + \sqrt {{x^2} - 8x + 41} $ .

My approach is as follow

$y = \sqrt {{x^2} + 4x + 4 + 9}  + \sqrt {{x^2} - 8x + 16 + 25}  \Rightarrow y = \sqrt {{{\left( {x + 2} \right)}^2} + 9}  + \sqrt {{{\left( {x - 4} \right)}^2} + 25} $

Within the square roots the minimum values are 3 and 5 hence the minimum value should be greeter than 8 but not able to find the actual minimum value.

Comment: Take points $(-2, 3), (x, 0), (4, -5)$. Value of $x$ that makes these points collinear should be the min

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to do a geometrical solution, but looks like that's already been done.

As for a calculus solution, we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}+\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}}$$
As, you have already shown $\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}>0$ and $\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}>0$ from completing the square. Hence, the only critical points occur when the RHS is equal to zero.
$$\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}+\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}}=0$$
$$\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}=-\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}}$$
$$\frac{x^2+4x+4}{x^2+4x+13}=\frac{x^2-8x+16}{x^2-8x+41}$$
$$\frac{x^2+4x+4}{x^2+4x+13}-1=\frac{x^2-8x+16}{x^2-8x+41}-1$$
$$\frac{-9}{x^2+4x+13}=\frac{-25}{x^2-8x+41}$$
$$9x^2-72x+369=25x^2+100x+325$$
$$16x^2+172x-44=0$$
$$4x^2+43x-11=0$$
$$(4x-1)(x+11)=0$$
$$x=-11,\frac{1}{4}$$
However, since we squared both sides of the equation, we expect one of the solutions to be extranneous. Note that if $x=-11$, then $x+2$ and $x-4$ are both negative. Hence, $\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}$ and $\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}}$ will have the same sign. Then of course we could not have $\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}=-\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+41}}$. So our solution is $x=\frac{1}{4}$. It is not hard to deduce that this is a minima.

So the minimum value of $y$ is
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}+14}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}+39}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{225}{16}}+\sqrt{\frac{625}{16}}$$
$$=\frac{15}{4}+\frac{25}{4}$$
$$=\boxed{10}$$

Answer (score 10):

I'll approach as geometry.

Let three point as $A(-2,-3), P(x,0), B(4,5)$. Then $y=\overline{AP}+\overline{PB}$.

By triangle inequality, $y\ge\overline{AB}=10$.

So the minimum value is $10$.

Comment: Really nice. (+1)

Comment: Make that +2. You beat me to the punch!